# PostgreSQL - How can I SUM until a certain hour of the day?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a metric for a PostgreSQL integrated dashboard which would show today's "Total Payment Value" (TPV) of a certain product, as well as yesterday's TPV of the same product, up until the same moment as today, so if I'm accessing the dashboard at 5 pm, it will show what it was yesterday until 5 pm and today's TPV.

edit: My question wasn't very clear so I'm adding a few more lines and editing the query, which had a mistake.

I tried this:

```
select
  sum(case when table.product in (13,14,15,16) then amount else 0 end) as "TPV"
  ,date_trunc('day', table.date) as "Day"
from table
where 
  date > current_date - 1
group by date_trunc('day', table.date)
order by 2,1
```

I only want to sum the amount when product = 13, 14, 15 or 16

An example of the product, date and amount would be like this:

```
product amount  date
8   4750    19/03/2019 00:21
14  7840    12/04/2019 22:40
14  15000   22/03/2019 18:27
14  11715   19/03/2019 00:12
14  1054    22/03/2019 18:22
14  18491   17/03/2019 14:28
14  12253   17/03/2019 14:30
14  27600   17/03/2019 14:32
14  3936    17/03/2019 14:28
14  19007   19/03/2019 00:14
8   9400    19/03/2019 00:21
8   4750    19/03/2019 00:21
8   25000   19/03/2019 00:17
14  10346   22/03/2019 18:23
```

I would like to have a metric that always calculates the sum of the product value today up until the current moment - when the "product" corresponds to values 13, 14, 15 or 16 - as well as the same metric for yesterday, e.g., it's 1 PM now, I want today's TPV until 1 PM and yesterday's TPV until 1 PM as well!

Comment: What is the table schema?

Comment: What do you mean? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: What are the columns of the table and their types?

Comment: Your description of the question .."*as well as yesterday's TPV of the same product, up until the same moment as today,*"  isn't clear and difficult to see what you want, especially since your query isn't telling us anything like that. So, it would help if you edit your question and add some sample rows of your table and the expected output, all in **plain-text** format.

Comment: I see my apologies, I will edit my question!

Comment: jmelesky, the table consists of transactions beginning in 2018 up until now, there are a lot of different columns, such as card data of the buyer, email, phone, etc.. as well as things like transaction ID, amount (value of the product), date and many more, an example of the date column would be this: "2019-03-22 18:27:48"